# ApplicationShutdownHooks Memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, out-of-memory

**java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks object might be causing a memory leak.**

While running the spring boot application for a long time, this memory leak is coming and the system got crashed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use log4j 2.13+, you can set `-Dlog4j2.isWebapp=true`, or `-Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false` if you use older 2.x log4j version.
Log4j uses hooks via DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry otherwise.